# Magento 2 Parent's theme styles are not loading in the child theme

Tags: magento2, custom-theme, parent-child-theme, developer-mode

I have create a child theme that extends from magento-luma theme by following the steps below:

> app/design/frontend/Company/parent/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Company/parent',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/design/frontend/Company/parent/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Parent Theme</title>
    <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
</theme>
```

> app/design/frontend/Company/parent/web/css/source/_extend.less

```
body{
  background-color: red;
}
```

After activating this theme from from magento admin. it works fine, load parent luma styles , images and js perfectly.
When I make another child theme that extends with the parent theme created above. It does not load the its parent themes styles and all other static assets.

I created the grand-child theme as follows.

> app/design/frontend/Company/child/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Company/child',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/design/frontend/Company/child/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Child Theme</title>
    <parent>Company/parent</parent>
</theme>
```

> app/design/frontend/Company/child/web/css/source/_extend.less

```
body{
  color: yellow;
}
```

[image: This is the result that I see on the browser]

Comment: do you run setup upgrade and static content deploy command after creating all above files ?

Comment: @Dhaval Solanki .Yes I run both commands but result is the same, _extend.less file is being override.